# How do I store the links of a webpage in a set using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to store the HTML links of a webpage in a set. (Since sets don't allow duplicate strings?)

Followed by parsing the HTML from those links

Then Storing the parsed links in another set.

So far all I have gotten is this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)").get();

    Elements links = doc.select("body a");

    System.out.println(links);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Elements` class implements the interface `java.util.List<E>`, there is an easy way to convert your collection of links to a set without duplicates.

This should work:

```
Set<Element> linkSet = new HashSet<Element>(links);
```

References:

JavaDocs `HashSet` - [java.util.HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Jsoup Docs `Elements`- [org.jsoup.select.Elements](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html)

Comment: Set<Element> linkSet = new HashSet<Element>(links); 
gives an error in Eclipse.

"The Constructor HashSet<Element>(Elements) is undefined"

Comment: I cannot check it right now, but some tweaking should make it work. I think it's unnecessary to iterate over the whole list.

Comment: I was wondering if linkSet.addAll(links); would work but then it tells me that links have to be a collection of Element rather than Elements. I change it to this and then I get a compile time error "cannot convert from Elements to Collection<? extends Element>"

Comment: I've been able to try the above answer, but it doesn't give me any compilation errors, but instead the desired `Set` object. Are you copying this verbatim, `Set<Element> linkSet = new HashSet<Element>(links);` ? In your above comment you are using the `Elements` class as the argument to the `HashSet` constructor which obviously is wrong.

Comment: `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)").get();    Elements links = doc.select("body a");    Set<Element> linkSet = new HashSet<Element>(links);` 
This is what I am running and it gives me the error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Elements to Collection<? extends Element>"

Comment: Are your imports correct? Here is a short working example:
https://pastee.org/f3cbb

Comment: I was missing: `import org.jsoup.nodes.Element; `

I'm surprised that Eclipse didn't suggest to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse the Element's in `links` with

```
for (Element e : links) {
    // called for every element, add them to a set if you wish
}
```